# How to merge sets which have intersections (connected components algorithm)?

Tags: python, set, graph-theory

Is there any effective way to merge sets which have intersections. For example:

```
l = [{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 5}, {7, 5}, {8, 9}]
```

The expected result is:

```
r = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9}]
```

All sets which have intersection (common components) should be merged. For example:

```
{1, 3} & {2, 3}
# {3}
```

So these two sets should be merged:

```
{1, 3} | {2, 3}
# {1, 2, 3}
```

Unfortunately I don't have any working solution.

UPDATE: The order of sets in the result is not important.

Comment: Please specify on what condition it should be merged ?

Comment: Looks like you want a [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) algorithm.

Comment: To avoid speculative answers, please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve, and show what you have already tried and what the problem was.

Comment: What's the desired output for an input like `[{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}]`? `[{1,2,3,4}]`? Or maybe `[{1,2,3}, {3,4}]`?

Comment: They should have intersection `{1, 3} & {2, 3}` -> `{3}` or `{4, 5}, {6, 5}, {7, 5}` -> `{5}`.

Comment: use the builtin `set.intersection`

Comment: Again, what should be the result for `l = [{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}]`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yes. It's right.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The result must be `{1, 2, 3, 4}`

Comment: I don't understand what you want, should they merge like `{1, 3} & {2, 3} -> {3}` or like `{1, 2, 3}`. Is my answer correct ?

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte `{1, 3}` and `{2, 3}` schould be merged to `{1, 2, 3}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An efficient way to implement the [connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) as mentioned by @mkrieger1 in the comments is to convert the list of sets to a set of hashable frozensets so that as you iterate through it and find a frozenset that intersects with the current one you can easily remove it from the pool:

```
pool = set(map(frozenset, l))
groups = []
while pool:
    groups.append(set(pool.pop()))
    while True:
        for candidate in pool:
            if groups[-1] & candidate:
                groups[-1] |= candidate
                pool.remove(candidate)
                break
        else:
            break
```

Given `l = [{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 5}, {7, 5}, {8, 9}]`, `groups` will become:

```
[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9}]
```

And given `l = [{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {2, 3}]`, `groups` will become:

```
[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

And given `l = [{1}, {2}, {1, 2}]`, `groups` will become:

```
[{1, 2}]
```

Comment: Is this an expected result or a bug `[{1}, {2}, {1, 2}]`:`[{1, 2}, {1}]`

Comment: Indeed that's a bug. I've fixed it with a `while` loop then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution:

```
def merge_sets(set_list):
    if len(set_list) == 0:
        # short circuit to avoid errors
        return []

    current_set = set_list[0]
    new_set_list = [current_set, ]

    for s in set_list[1:]:          # iterate from the second element
        if len(current_set.intersection(s)) > 0:
            current_set.update(s)
        else:
            current_set = set(s)    # copy
            new_set_list.append(current_set)

    return new_set_list
```

The test cases this works for:

```
test_cases = [
    {
        'input': [{1, 3}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 5}, {7, 5}, {8, 9}],
        'output': [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9}],
    },
    {
        'input': [{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}],
        'output': [{1, 2, 3, 4}, ],
    },
    {
        'input': [{1}, {2}, {1, 2}],
        'output': [{1}, {1, 2}],
    },
    {
        'input': [{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {2, 3}],
        'output': [{1, 2}, {2, 3, 4}],
    },
]

for case in test_cases:
    print('input   ', case['input'])
    print('expected', case['output'])

    new_output = merge_sets(case['input'])
    print('real    ', new_output)
    assert new_output == case['output']
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: `[{1}, {1, 2}]` there is an intersection there so the output is wrong

Comment: Note: my solution does consider the order of the sets in the input list. Is that what you need @MykolaZotko? Or could the input be a unordered group of sets that should be merged till there is no more merging to do?

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte should the algorithm consider the order of the input sets? If yes, then my solution works; if not, then my solution is not the correct one

Comment: for `[{1}, {2}, {1,2}]` , The result must be `{1, 2}` not `{1}, {1, 2}`

Comment: @BenoîtPilatte The order is not important.